Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-permissions'
I try to use filePicker https://github.com/prabudevarrajan/nativescript-plugin-filepicker
and receive error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-permissions' in '...'
but package https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-permissions is disabled.
My App_Resources\Android\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml has relevant lines for permission:
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

My working environment:
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/animations": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/common": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/core": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/forms": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/router": "~16.2.0",
 "@nativescript-community/arraybuffers": "^1.1.5",
 "@nativescript-community/ui-drawer": "^0.1.27",
 "@nativescript-community/ui-svg": "^0.1.33",
 "@nativescript/angular": "^16.0.0",
 "@nativescript/core": "~8.6.0",
 "@nativescript/secure-storage": "^3.0.3",
 "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
 "@prabudevarrajan/filepicker": "^2.0.0",
 "nativescript-clipboard": "^2.1.1",
 "platform": "^1.3.6",
 "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
 "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~16.2.0",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "~16.2.0",
 "@nativescript/android": "8.6.2",
 "@nativescript/preview-cli": "1.0.13",
 "@nativescript/types": "~8.6.0",
 "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.18",
 "@ngtools/webpack": "~16.2.0",
 "@types/platform": "^1.3.6",
 "typescript": "~5.1.6"
},

and building log:
assets by status 18.7 MiB [emitted]
   asset vendor.js 18 MiB [emitted] (name: vendor) (id hint: defaultVendor)
   asset bundle.js 604 KiB [emitted] (name: bundle)
   asset runtime.js 88.6 KiB [emitted] [compared for emit] (name: runtime)
Entrypoint bundle 18.7 MiB = runtime.js 88.6 KiB vendor.js 18 MiB bundle.js 604 KiB
  runtime modules 25.4 KiB 13 modules
  orphan modules 461 bytes [orphan] 5 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 5.72 MiB
  javascript modules 5.46 MiB 588 modules
json modules 273 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/mdn-data/css/*.json 242 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/css-tree/ 30.7 KiB 2 modules
modules by path ./src/ 204 KiB
  modules by path ./src/app/ 81.7 KiB 16 modules
modules by path ./src/*.ts 4.76 KiB
 ./src/polyfills.ts 545 bytes [built] [code generated]
 ./src/main.ts 4.23 KiB [built] [code generated]
 ./src/app.css 118 KiB [built] [code generated]
external "~/package.json" 42 bytes [optional] [built] [code generated]

 ERROR in ./node_modules/@prabudevarrajan/filepicker/index.android.js 3:0-56
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-permissions' in 'E:\NativeScript\...\node_modules\@prabudevarrajan\filepicker'

any ideas?

Add plugin for nativescript permissions
"nativescript-permissions": "~1.3.12" in package.json, run npm install and try to run the application again

@ParthPatel, Thank you. Despite this package deprecated? Ok, I tried this, application working, module found, at common this is solution - to use that deprecated packages. But I'm faced with error message on console -  "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE": false. I use for debugging API 30 Android 11. Absent permissions, of course, this is another question, than absent module, you can write your advice as solution. But do you have any idea how to add needed permissions?


replace exisiting READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission with this

Run ns clean platform android
re-run the application.

